# BroadcastReceiver for location

Tags: android, locationlistener, android-location

I know BroadcastReceiver watches for text, phone events, etc... but can you run LocationServices as a service and event based on Location?

For example, you are near a certain GPS point and the phone notifies you.

Comment: Here you go http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this.  There is a version of `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` that takes a `PendingIntent` as a parameter, and this Intent could be used to fire a `BroadcastReceiver`.  This code will register a custom broadcast to fire with the location updates.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("UNIQUE_BROADCAST_ACTION_STRING_HERE");
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
long minTime;     //This should probably be fairly long
float minDistance; //This should probably be fairly big
String provider;   //GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER

PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, launchIntent);
```

Then you just have to register your `BroadcastReceiver` with the same Intent action and it will receive the location updates for processing.  And, of course, keep that `PendingIntent` around because you'll need to call `manager.removeUpdates(launchIntent)` at some point!

**Final Note:**

Because it sounds like you are trying to implement regular location updates while your app isn't in the foreground, keep this in mind.  Unless you want your app branded as a battery killer, be extremely careful with how you implement this functionality.

You will want to greatly reduce the frequency up location updates with either a large minTime or minDistance parameter to allow the location service to rest.  This feature should also be attached to a user controlled preference so they can enable/disable your app from tracking location in the background.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: @Wireless-Designs, you are a Gem, I thought this was the case, I am still learning about INTENT for the Droid, you response is very informative - thanks for your time kind sir!

Comment: No problem.  If this answer ends up solving your problem, feel free to accept it.  Cheers!

Comment: I will, I wanted to test first ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to do this with a service and the alert manager with no luck. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 22):

This question is more then 2 years old but there is now very very easy and battery efficient way to do this. The concept is called *Geofences*. You can learn it in more detail below:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: So how do you propose this would work? Set a geofence for the user's current location for lets say 50m radius, then on exit event, set a new geofence with the same radius, and that way track a user's movement?

Comment: @Pierre: if you want to update based on location change, have a look at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)

Comment: Thanks @serv-inc, I have used extactly that. And to save battery power, I'm only logging locations with accuracy lower than 40m, I have also added a static variable called previous location, if the new location is farther than 40m from the previous location, I log it, else not.

Comment: Note that the this Geofencing api requires play services, as opposed to `LocationManager` which comes with AOSP.