# Android: broadcast receiver to get GPS position

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i would like to be notified when the user is near a certain GPS position with a specific intent filter: do you know if it is possible in an Android app?

Comment: These may help you.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240246/broadcastreceiver-for-location

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you should look at `LocationManager.addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)`.  When you are within proximity of the GPS coords the `PendingIntent` will be fired off.