# How Get Server Cal Responsive Fast,while running service

Tags: android

Hi am doing beacon ranging application, here continuously i need run my service in background,while running service my foreground application server api cals taking time to respond,after send request and getting response in middlle am getting some service bluetooth related logs..like below

onScanResult() - Device=20:CD:39:A1:4F:65 RSSI=-68
stopLeScan()

please can u any one suggest me how to cal webservices  fast responsive with out stop service running,and bluetooth enable

Answer (score 0):

By default `Service` in Android is executing in main thread. Try to execute service in separate thread.

This may help you: http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Comment: Thank you i am creating one thread in side run() am calling sercice but same prblem coming

Comment: new Thread() {
           public void run() {

             BeaconStreamApplication myEntrypoint = new BeaconStreamApplication(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
               Home.this, "com.beaconstream.com", "9876543211",
               "1234567891", "Wa96IhgkrHzcqacITPRe6Wuz3",
               "3oQtNmonUTwtayOOomR2Vk0y1rfhViw4qRBVxXuYGznDJ76j9K",
               "1440791", user_id, R.drawable.app_icon);
                       }
          }.start(); i did like that

Comment: Why not google a bit? :)
Try other solutions, running only part of service in separate thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556752/android-how-to-run-service-in-different-thread-than-main-thread