# BroadcastReceiver for Google Play Location Service (setting of the Status Bar)

Tags: android, geolocation, broadcastreceiver, google-play-services, android-settings

I'm trying to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for get the state changes of `Location` settings

[image: Location settings]

But I didn't find any documentation for doing it. I only found `BroadcastReceiver` to check the status of certain search providers (*`GPS` and `Network providers`*); but not for checking if this particular option (`Location`) is active or not in the system preferences.

Somebody can show me the right direction?

> **NOTE:**
>
> I used **Google Play Location Service** (*`com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` interface*).

Comment: i think that this [link][1] should help you.

Cheers !


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5240774/3351735

Comment: Thanks @Kansen, but that isn't exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found one way to check if the "`Location`" setting of the `action bar` is enabled or disabled; but **without** a `BroadcastReceiver` (*a shame, really*)

```
private static final String TAG = getClass().getName();

/* We define the LocationManager */
LocationManager location_Manager= (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

/* If the GPS provider or the network provider are enabled; the Location setting is enabled.*/
if(location_Manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || location_Manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "The Location setting is enabled");
}else{
   /* We send the user to the "Location activity" to enable the setting */
   Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

I really did not need a `BroadcastReceiver`; since the "*arquitecture*" that has my app allows me to do without it; but I would have liked to know how to use it.

> **NOTICE:**
>
> If someone finds the way to make it with a `BroadcastReceiver` I will change my correct answer by her answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Location Listener.

> onProviderDisabled(String provider)
>   Called when the provider is disabled by the user.

Compare to provider String such as
provider.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: Hi, Pham Hung. I can't test your answer now, but I will try it in few hours and then, if it works, I will accept your answer. But looks ok, +1

Comment: I tried to use the information in your answer, but, unfortunately, I used `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` in this project, so I haven't got access to the methods of `android.location.LocationListener` interface.