# Service does not stay on 24/7

Tags: android, android-service, android-location, location-services

I am trying to write a background service which shares location through SMS whenever the change in distance is more than 650 meters after every 3 minutes.

The code works fine but the service automatically closes after few minutes when I stop travelling. I want to keep the app running all the time so that the app sends data whenever a person is travelling.

Here is the code I wrote..

Main.java

```
package com.example.locationtest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


     // Method to start the service
       public void startService(View view) {
          startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class));
       }

       // Method to stop the service
       public void stopService(View view) {
          stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundService.class));
       }






}
```

BackgroundService.java

```
package com.example.locationtest;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BackgroundService extends Service {



        private static DataSharing data=new DataSharing();
        private Thread triggerService;
        protected LocationManager locationManager;
        protected MyLocationListener MyLocationListener;
        protected Criteria criteria;

        public static final int MIN_TIME = 18000; 
        public static final long MIN_DISTANCE = 650; 

        private SharedPreferences settings;


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
             data.setContext(getApplicationContext()); 


            addLocationListener();

            return START_STICKY;
        }

        private void addLocationListener()
        {
            triggerService = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        Looper.prepare();        


                        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                        criteria = new Criteria();
                        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

                        final String PROVIDER = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                        updateLocation(getLastBestLocation(MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE));

                        MyLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, MyLocationListener);



                        Looper.loop();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, "LocationThread");
            triggerService.start();
        }


        public Location getLastBestLocation(int minDistance, long minTime) {
            Location bestResult = null;
            float bestAccuracy = Float.MAX_VALUE;
            long bestTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

            List<String> matchingProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();
            for (String provider: matchingProviders) {
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (location != null) {
                    float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                    long time = location.getTime();

                    if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
                        bestResult = location;
                        bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                        bestTime = time;
                    }
                    else if (time < minTime && bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime) {
                        bestResult = location;
                        bestTime = time;
                    }
                }
            }

            return bestResult;
        }

        public static void updateLocation(Location location)
        {


            double latitude, longitude;

            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            data.sendSms(latitude, longitude, new Date());




        }


        class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {

                    updateLocation(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }

    }
```

DataSharing.java

```
package com.example.locationtest;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class DataSharing {
    String message="";
    String phoneNo="0300phone#";
    Context mAppContext;
    public DataSharing()
    {

    }

    public DataSharing(Context context)
    {
        mAppContext=context;
    }
    public void setContext(Context context)
    {
        mAppContext=context;
    }

    public void sendSms(double clat,double clong,Date d)
    {
        message="Traffic-Advisor123 Latitude:"+String.valueOf(clat)+"\nLongitude:"+String.valueOf(clong)+"\nTime:"+String.valueOf(d);
        try {
             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
             smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }             
    }
    public void sendViaNetwork(double clat,double clong,Date d)
    {
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

    }
}
```

Another problem that I face is that sometimes SMS gets sent even before the 3 minutes have passed. May be that is because some other app asks for location which gets shared with my app as well. I can only process data if its sent with an interval no less than 2 minutes. How can I restrict it to 2+ minutes?

I am looking for some guidance. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Services are not really supposed to run continually in the background. Perhaps you should be using a BroadcastReceiver and the answer to this other question may be what you are looking for: [BroadcastReceiver for location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240246/broadcastreceiver-for-location)