# RequestLocationUpdates Time of life

Tags: android, locationmanager

RequestLocationUpdates is a method of LocationManager, receives GPS information periodically.

I think if I send from onCreate application should not be a problem because it will not overcharge the main thread, I'm right?

If I want to receive information requestLocationUpdates, even after the application closed, from where should I send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the best solution I found was to use Service, as follows:

```
public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    LocationManager LocManager =(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("location", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    Log.i("location", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.i("info", "Provider OFF");
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.i("info", "Provider ON");
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.i("LocAndroid", "Provider Status: " + status);
    Log.i("info", "Provider Status: " + status);
}

}
```

And in onCreate () I launch the service:

```
public class PacienteApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GpsService.class);
    this.startService(intent);
}
}
```

Using Broadcast Receiver is a good idea, but laborious as they are not allowed to use handlers within this class. And anyway you need the service to run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the most part you will want to register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). one of the broadcasts that you can watch for is when the location changes. There are a few logistical concerns with this such as how to interact with the BroadcastReceiver and how much battery your application will consume. A good summary of how to address these concerns can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240246/broadcastreceiver-for-location).

Essentially you will want to make an Intent (your specific way of identfying an event you're looking for has happened) and a PendingIntent(A way to make that event interact with LocationServices).

```
PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, launchIntent);
```